# How do I compare two complex data structures?

Tags: python, data-structures, comparison

I have some nested datastructures, each something like:

```
[ ('foo', [ {'a':1, 'b':2},
                 {'a':3.3, 'b':7} ]),
  ('bar', [ {'a':4, 'd':'efg', 'e':False} ])   ]
```

I need to compare these structures, to see if there are any differences. Short of writing a function to explicitly walk the structure, is there an existing library or method of doing this kind of recursive comparison?

Comment: what are you comparing to what?

Comment: Do you need to just see if they are equal or not, or actually find where they differ?

Comment: Find where they differ, if they do.

Comment: To see where they differ, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26171760/5069869

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in aggregation types (`list`, `tuple`, `dict`, etc.) already support equality and relational comparison. For types you create, you need to implement the [rich comparison methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

Answer (score 3):

Your example data structures will already do appropriate equality testing, because you are using built-in data types which properly implement `__eq__` and `__ne__`, including recursing into nested values.

If you want to include your own classes, you need to implement both of these methods (note that implementing `__eq__` *does not* imply that if you do a != comparison your `__eq__` will be called, you must implement `__ne__`, too).

Answer (score 0):

If I don't need to use the diff within Python itself, I would probably end up hacking it. Convert both to yaml, and run a diff on them. :D