# Python: Inheriting builtin types dict and list

Tags: python, inheritance, built-in, built-in-types

I have always been confused and falling over the minute details while inheriting the builtin types in Python e.g. list and dict.

Can you please point to the tutorials and docs which give a comprehensive details about the internals and the syntax involved.

Comment: "minute details"?  Like?  For Example?

Comment: If your code will depend on the internal details, what happens when the internals change?

Comment: you have not read any docs? or? which one? specific questions please...

Comment: Suppose I am inheriting dict. I am a bit confused about things like how do you I refer the key-value pairs inside the class. If I use self[key] it clobbers with the internal __dict__

Answer (score 2):

[Python Language Reference, §3.4.6, "Emulating container types"](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types)

Answer (score 0):

this is for Dict:

http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html

Edit

update userdict docs link:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the custom `trackingdict` class in my answer to a different Stack Overflow question titled [*Recursive diff of two python dictionaries (keys and values)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903720/recursive-diff-of-two-python-dictionaries-keys-and-values/5904056#5904056) which shows it actually being done. It overrides all the methods which can mutate a dictionary object.