# Dictionary recursive compare program

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a program that compares two python dictionaries and outputs the differences of the two.  It works with a dict that has a depth of 2 or less.  What should I do to be able to handle dicts with more depth, also nested dicts?

Another problem that I am having is when I pass a json array through my get_json() function it returns as a list.  And the program is bugging out with the list instead of a dict.  How should i go about solving that?

My program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import json

def get_json():
    file_name = raw_input("Enter name of JSON File: ")
    with open(file_name) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        return json_data

def print_diff(json1, json2):
    for n in json1:
        if n not in json2:
            print('-   "' + str(n) + '":')
    for n in json2:
        if n not in json1:
            print('+   "' + str(n) + '":')
            continue
        if json2[n] != json1[n]:
            if type(json2[n]) not in (dict, list):
                print('-   "' + str(n) + '" : "' + str(json1[n]))
                print('+   "' + str(n) + '" : "' + str(json2[n]))
            else:
                if type(json2[n]) == dict:
                    print_diff(json1[n], json2[n])
                    continue
    return


def main():
    file1 = get_json()
    print(type(file1))
    file2 = get_json()
    print(type(file2))
    print_diff(file1, file2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

example of dict 1:

```
{
    "widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        },
        "image": {
            "src": "Images/Sun.png",
            "name": "sun1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 250,
            "alignment": "center"
        },
        "text": {
            "data": "Click Here",
            "size": 36,
            "style": "bold",
            "name": "text1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center",
            "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
    }
}
```

example of dict 2:

```
{
    "widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        },
        "image": {
            "src": "Images/Sun.png",
            "name": "sun2",
            "hOffset": 100,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center"
        },
        "text": {
            "data": "Click Here",
            "size": 36,
            "style": "bold",
            "name": "text1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center",
            "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
    }
}
```

example output:

```
Enter name of JSON File: JSON1.json
<type 'dict'>
Enter name of JSON File: JSON2.json
<type 'dict'>
-   "vOffset" : "250
+   "vOffset" : "100
-   "name" : "sun1
+   "name" : "sun2
-   "hOffset" : "250
+   "hOffset" : "100
```

Answer (score 2):

I have written following code which can compare two dictionaries with different depths and print the differences to console output. Please note that, if the key is found in first dictionary and not found in second, it would just print only not found key (it will not print under lying tree). I hope this is what expected. This code works for one way comparison, so you need to make two calls for comparing dictionary in other way.

```
def findDiff(d1, d2, path=""):
    for k in d1.keys():
        if not d2.has_key(k):
            print path, ":"
            print k + " as key not in d2", "\n"
        else:
            if type(d1[k]) is dict:
                if path == "":
                    path = k
                else:
                    path = path + "->" + k
                findDiff(d1[k],d2[k], path)
            else:
                if d1[k] != d2[k]:
                    print path, ":"
                    print " - ", k," : ", d1[k]
                    print " + ", k," : ", d2[k] 

print "comparing s1 to s2:"
print findDiff(s1,s2)
print "comparing s2 to s1:"
print findDiff(s2,s1)
```

Output::

```
comparing s1 to s2:
widget->text :
data as key not in d2 
widget->text->window->image :
 -  vOffset  :  250
 +  vOffset  :  100
widget->text->window->image :
 -  name  :  sun1
 +  name  :  sun2
widget->text->window->image :
 -  hOffset  :  250
 +  hOffset  :  100
None
comparing s2 to s1:
widget->text->window->image :
 -  vOffset  :  100
 +  vOffset  :  250
widget->text->window->image :
 -  name  :  sun2
 +  name  :  sun1
widget->text->window->image :
 -  hOffset  :  100
 +  hOffset  :  250
None
```

Please note that, in your question you have not considered if there is a difference in key , path of the key is not printed. I am printing it in my code. I have deleted data element from widget->text for testing. so, pls ignore this console output

Answer (score 0):

Without reading all to much of your stuff,

```
def check_dict(first, second):
    for key in first:
        for keyTwo in second:

            if type(first[key]) == dict and type(second[keyTwo]) == dict:
                return check_dict(first[key], second[keyTwo])
            if not first[key] == second[keyTwo]:
                return false
```

Don't have access for a python interpreter at the moment but something along the lines of this should work. It's just a start for an idea but hopefully this is enough information to spark something.