# Python: Tool to compare pairs of dicts of varying deepness?

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I have a couple of pairs of rather big dicts. The structure of the pair dicts is exactly the same but the values will differ. All pairs differ in how nested they are.

To clarify:

- `dict_a` has same structure as `dict_b`
- `dict_c` has same structure as `dict_d` (but is different from dict_a and dict_b)

etc.

Is there a tool out there that makes it easy to implement a function to compare **the values only**, and/or do some basic arithmetic on them? My dicts can be quite nested, so a simple `[for k,v in dict_x.iteritems()...]` won't do.

Comment: Just the pairs, so: a to b, c to d etc

Comment: my answer at this page might help to compare two dictionries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423384/dictionary-recursive-compare-program/21432510#21432510

Comment: Yeah, that is a starting point. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a problem for...recursive functions!

Basically, if I understand your question, you have a deep dictionary with varying levels of depths at unspecified keys. You'd like to compare the values of `dict_a` to `dict_b` but don't care much about the keys: just the differences in values. Here's an idea using a recursive function to print out each set of values that doesn't match.

```
def dict_compare(da, db):
    for k, v in da.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict): #if the value is another dict:
            dict_compare(v, db[k]) #enter into the comparison function again!
        else:
            if v != db[k]: 
                print 'values not equal at', k
```

Then you just can call

```
dict_compare(dict_a, dict_b)
```

The magic being that if the value of a given key is in fact another dictionary, just call your comparison function again.

Obviously, if you wanted to do something more complicated than just print the simple key of the values that don't match, just modify what happens after the `if v != db[k]` line.