# Strict Comparison of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, equality

I'm having a little bit of trouble comparing two similar dictionaries. I would like stricter comparison of the values (and probably keys).

Here's the really basic problem:

```
>>> {'a': True} == {'a': 1}
True
```

Similarly (and somewhat confusingly):

```
>>> {1: 'a'} == {True: 'a'}
True
```

This makes sense because `True == 1`. What I'm looking for is something that behaves more like `is`, but compares two possibly nested dictionaries. Obviously you can't use use `is` on the two dictionaries, because that will always return `False`, even if all of the elements are identical.

My current solution is to just use `json.dumps` to get a string representation of both and compare that.

```
>>> json.dumps({'a': True}, sort_keys=True) == json.dumps({'a': 1}, sort_keys=True)
False
```

But this only works if everything is JSON-serializable.

I also tried comparing all of the keys and values manually:

```
>>> l = {'a': True}
>>> r = {'a': 1}
>>> r.keys() == l.keys() and all(l[key] is r[key] for key in l.keys())
False
```

But this fails if the dictionaries have some nested structure. I figured I could write a recursive version of this to handle the nested case, but it seemed unnecessarily ugly and un-pythonic.

Is there a "standard" or simple way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea - small integers and strings that are valid identifiers compare OK with `is` because they're interned (in CPython at least), but you will quickly hit issues with anything non-trivial. What is the underlying problem that you were trying to solve that led you to `True` vs. `1` as a dictionary key?

Comment: some sample dictionaries with the nested cases you want to find would be nice

Comment: I have a `JSONField` in Django that stores some denormalized data. (It's product data). Having `{"assembly_required": True}` makes it clear that the product requires assembly, but `{"assembly_required": 1}` is slightly less clear.

DeepDiff looks like it will work. Just need to do a `DeepDiff(left, right) == {}`.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why the original comment mentioning [DeepDiff](https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff) was deleted, but OP didn't pull it out of thin air: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26171760/95852

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close with JSON: Use Python's `pprint` module instead. This is documented to sort dictionaries in Python [2.5+](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) and [3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html):

> Dictionaries are sorted by key before the display is computed.

Let's confirm this. Here's a session in Python 3.6 (which conveniently preserves insertion order even for regular `dict` objects):

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = {2: 'two', 3: 'three', 1: 'one'}
>>> b = {3: 'three', 2: 'two', 1: 'one'}
>>> a
{2: 'two', 3: 'three', 1: 'one'}
>>> b
{3: 'three', 2: 'two', 1: 'one'}
>>> a == b
True
>>> c = {2: 'two', True: 'one', 3: 'three'}
>>> c
{2: 'two', True: 'one', 3: 'three'}
>>> a == b == c
True
>>> from pprint import pformat
>>> pformat(a)
"{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}"
>>> pformat(b)
"{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}"
>>> pformat(c)
"{True: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}"
>>> pformat(a) == pformat(b)
True
>>> pformat(a) == pformat(c)
False
>>>
```

And let's quickly confirm that pretty-printing sorts nested dictionaries:

```
>>> a['b'] = b
>>> a
{2: 'two', 3: 'three', 1: 'one', 'b': {3: 'three', 2: 'two', 1: 'one'}}
>>> pformat(a)
"{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 'b': {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}}"
>>>
```

So, instead of serializing to JSON, serialize using `pprint.pformat()`. I imagine there may be some corner cases where two objects that you want to consider unequal nevertheless create the same pretty-printed representation. But those cases should be rare, and you wanted something simple and Pythonic, which this is.

Answer (score 1):

You can test identity of all (key, value) pairs element-wise:

```python
def equal_dict(d1, d2):
    return all((k1 is k2) and (v1 is v2)
               for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(d1.items(), d2.items()))

>>> equal_dict({True: 'a'}, {True: 'a'})
True

>>> equal_dict({1: 'a'}, {True: 'a'})
False
```

This should work with `float`, `int`, `str` and `bool`, but not other sequences or more complex objects.
Anyway, that's a start if you need it.

Comment: This doesn't work, because you are testing with `is`. Your tests happen to give the desired results due to interning and possibly other Python micro-optimizations. But it can incorrectly report two equal dictionaries as unequal. For example, instead of `'a'`, use two separate variables, and give those variables equal-but-not-interned values, such as large integers.

Comment: And, as you already said, it doesn't work for "sequences or more complex objects". So it doesn't meet OP's requirement that it handle nested structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance()` to delineate between a regular dictionary entry and a nested dictionary entry. This way you can iterate through using `is` to compare strictly, but also check when you need to dive down a level into the nested dictionary.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

```
myDict = {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': {'a': True}}
for key, value in myDict.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        # do what you need to do....
    else:
        # etc...
```

Comment: `isinstance(myDict, dict)` :.. myDict -> myDict[x] ?

Comment: fixed. Thanks for catching

Comment: I don't think that'll work either, x is just they key. Probably need myDict[x] to get the contents

Comment: or use `for x, y in myDict.items()`

Comment: Right, forgot how python dictionary iteration worked... bad answer. Let me edit again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this. However since you didn't provide example data I won't go into guessing what it could be

```
from boltons.itertools import remap

def compare(A, B): return A == B and type(A) == type(B)

dict_to_compare_against = { some dict }

def visit(path, key, value):
    cur = dict_to_compare_against
    for i in path:
        cur = cur[i]

    if not compare(cur, value):
        raise Exception("Not equal")


remap(other_dict, visit=visit)
```